# How do I transcribe a Masyu into a Google Sheets?

Tags: grid-deduction, masyu

I received some PDF puzzle books for Christmas and have been solving them in a Google Sheets. The basic tools of borders, background colors, and entering numbers work for lots of genres (Nurikabe, Tapa, Statue Park, Slitherlink, Sudoku...), but the next set of puzzles are [Masyus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masyu). Here is Wikipedia's example:

[image: example puzzle]

[image: example solution]

I have no idea how to represent this in Google Sheets. The circles I can do fine; I'll copy over some Unicode characters. But how do I draw the loop? It's not along the edge of cells as in Slitherlink, which is a loop genre I do fine in Sheets. Note that the loop will even need to enter cells with characters in them, which wouldn't be a worry in, say, Yajilin.

The Sheets aspect is pretty non-negotiable unless it's completely impossible. I want to have all my solutions neatly organized together on the spreadsheet, I want to solve when I don't have internet, I can't do Excel since 1) I know it poorly and 2) I'll lose my Office in few years when I graduate, and solving in the original PDF isn't an option since I loathe solving puzzles in image editors. That basically leaves Sheets. **I would appreciate if answers took using Google Sheets for granted** and refrained from recommending other tools.

How do I transcribe a Masyu into a Google Sheets, preferably as simply as possible?

Comment: This is a complete loophole, but Insert -> Drawing will allow you to use a vector image editor. You say you "loathe solving puzzles in image editors" and I have no idea whether that does or doesn't extend to vector editors. If you never tried them I would recommend them for solving these types of puzzles (although Google Drawing does not support layers and locking of layers).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I could do it like this:

[image]

... taking 4 cells (2×2) as one cell in Masyu puzzle.

The circles are not unicode characters, but images, those entered to the sheet by

```
+ > Image > Image over cells.
```

Once you enter the image you can resize it to fit a 2×2 region. Then you can copy and paste it in the corresponding cell by selecting the top left cell of the 2×2 box.

This was created on mobile, therefore selecting regions to shade borders were sometimes a little bit difficult (with fingers), but I believe it is easier on a desktop.

Comment: I appreciate that this takes up less cells than the other answer, lets me use borders (I like that for loop puzzles), and taught me about "image over cells", so I have accepted it.

Comment: I have been using this to solve the Masyu puzzles and it's been working wonderfully

Answer (score 3):

What about translating each cell in the original to a 3x3 block of cells in Google Sheets? Then e.g. row 1 column 2 would have cells highlighted like:

```
...
.##
.#.
```

Answer (score 2):

Building on from Ed Murphy's answer, I put together a sheet using checkboxes for the lines, and uses box drawing characters to complete the look:

[image]

It uses conditional formatting to make the line stand out more, and to bring attention to errors in the solution.

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w0OrvC5_4EPu9WI1GREUnbXWe4LpNU8z3VlXdVS0Wj4/edit#gid=0) is a link if you want to make a copy.

Comment: While this works, it's more complicated to set up, and I don't really like the checkboxes breaking up the thin line

Comment: Fair call. I was going for ease of input, rather than being visually nice