# How do I transcribe a KenKen into a Google Sheets?

Tags: grid-deduction

Similar to [this previous question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119212/how-do-i-transcribe-a-masyu-into-a-google-sheets), I have been slowly working through some PDF puzzle books. I will shortly come up on KenKen puzzles (called TomTom in the book, but the format is the same). Here is an example from the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KenKen):

[image: blank puzzle] [image: puzzle with solution]

I can very easily draw the cages by thickening some borders, and the cells which have only solution-numbers should be simple as well. However, I'm not sure how to put the problem-numbers (11+, 20x) so that they share a box with a solution-number. I would prefer for the solution-numbers to look the same in all cells but if I have to modify them somehow to make them share space with problem-numbers that is fine with me.

Google Sheets is non-negotiable. I am not willing to use an inserted drawing, as suggested by a [comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119212/how-do-i-transcribe-a-masyu-into-a-google-sheets#comment333004_119212) to the previous question. Within these constraints, how do I transcribe a KenKen into a Google Sheets as simply as possible? Solutions which take up less cells of of the underlying Google Sheets are preferred.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, resize the rows and columns like this:

[image: 1]

Then create the cages using `borders` option.

[image: 2]

After that, select the rows with a short height and adjust the font size.

[image: 3]

Then insert the clues.

[image: 4]

Finally, select the down-arrow next to the tab name and turn off `Gridlines`.

[image: 5]

And solve the puzzle!

[image: 6]

Comment: PS: 2+ should actually be 2÷.

Comment: @bobble You don't need two columns (and hence 4 spreadsheet cells) for every puzzle cell.  Just have two rows in each cell, and make the top row left-justified and the bottom one centered.  Uses half as many cells.